# Pulling data from library and generate report

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, sharepoint-foundation

Has anybody work with helpdesk support, to generate in a page different reports from library that has  workflow.

We have two form libraries and we are trying to pulling data from that library and generate report. The client to see the number of requests, duration and escalation issues and what the admin team do.

Note:

BI(Business Intelligence) is not an option

Comment: "BI is not an option"?? BI means Business Intelligence. You want to report on data of your business. That ***IS*** BI.

Answer (score 2):

If the InfoPath forms expose form fields as SharePoint list columns, then you can export these list columns to Excel and create reports in Excel.

If the data is only in InfoPath forms and nothing is exposed as list columns, then you will need third party tools to extract that data and report on it.

One possible tool is DBXL by QDabra Software (not affiliated with me).

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) to do that. You can use the list or library as a data source for a report.

When creating the report, one of the options is SharePoint List. You specify the URL to site containing the list (or library) and choose the list, and the fields you want to use from the list.

You can apply filters to select the rows you need. You can use the data in any report control (tablix, chart, etc.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61944/discussion-on-answer-by-mannaggia-pulling-data-from-library-and-generate-report).